# Как изменить файл linux без прав

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

История такова: Искал я на просторах интернета как зарутить себя и нашёл какую-то статью. Там было написало изменить в passwd X:0:0. И я как самый умный так и сделал.
Debian сказал "Ты кто?" и sudo тоже перестал работать.
Устанавливал челез live поэтому пароля для root не поставил.
Сейчас сижу с того же live Debian'а и думаю что же мне делать...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbFT2.jpg!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWJP8.jpg) - bios с usb

Answer (score 1):

Перед модификацией **любого** системного файла необходимо выполнить команду

```
cp <faile-name> <file-name>.old
```

Сделали такой бэкап?  Подозреваю - нет.. Ну а хотя бы помните, что там было раньше? Если помните, то:

1. Грузимся LiveCD или флэшки. (Любой дистрибутив!)
2. После появления главного меню инсталлятора выбираем опцию "Попробовать"
3. Монтируем HDD
4. Идём в каталог /etc
5. Исправляем файл passwd
6. Пергружаемся....

Comment: Безо всяких liveCD такое чинится. Учитесь пользоваться встроенными средствами.

Comment: Спасибо, я догадался так сделать только не знал как смонтировать. Уже всё починил. Только теперь почему-то в bios не отображается загрузчик, я могу зайти с USB но встроенный не отображается

Comment: @Artem "в bios не отображается загрузчик" -  в меню установочного CD должно быть что-то вреде "Восстановить загрузчик".

Answer (score 1):

Можно загрузиться без пароля и без загрузочного DVD. Для этого нужно в начале загрузки, когда на несколько секунд появится меню GRUB (синий прямоугольник со списком вариантов загрузки), нажать клавишу «e» (английскую), это позволит изменить выбранный пункт меню (для текущей загрузки), откроется окно, в котором нужно найти строчку, начинающуюся на «linux», заканчиваться она скорее всего будет на «quiet» (обрати внимание, что содержимое там скорее всего не поместится на одну строку, то есть, оно будет перенесено на следующую). Клавишами управления курсора нужно перейти в конец той строки (т.е. после «quiet»), добавить пробел и далее «init=/bin/sh», этот параметр указывает ядру в качестве начального процесса загрузить оболочку /bin/sh, после этого нужно нажать комбинацию клавиш Ctrl-x, загрузка продолжится с изменёнными параметрами, и появится приглашение командной строки («#»), то есть, будет получен доступ с правами администратора без пароля.

Но, при этом, файловая система ещё будет смонтирована в режиме только для чтения. Чтобы что-то исправить, нужно перемонтировать корневую файловую систему в режиме для записи, это делается командой «mount -o remount,rw /». После этого можно восстановить содержимое файла /etc/passwd. Команды shutdown и reboot работать не будут, перед перезагрузкой можно на всякий случай перемонтировать корневую файловую систему обратно в режим для чтения («mount -o remount,ro /») и нажать кнопку Reset.

Теперь о том, как восстановить содержимое файла /etc/passwd. Рядом с ним может находиться его резервная копия, это может быть файл /etc/passwd- (с минусом на конце), также свою резервную копию мог создать текстовый редактор, который использовался для редактирования /etc/passwd. Перед исправлением содержимого файла /etc/passwd обязательно нужно сделать его копию! Если старое содержимое файла не сохранилось, то узнать, какие раньше были идентификаторы пользователя и группы по умолчанию (которые ты видимо заменил на 0 и 0) можно посмотрев их у домашнего каталога пользователя, при помощи команды ls, передав ей параметр «-n», то есть, таким образом: «ls -n /home» (или «ls -nd /home/username» — указав нужного пользователя вместо «username»).